# Entropy Rate of Bit String

Tags: entropy

1. How to calculate "Entropy Rate" of a bit string?
2. Does "NIST Randomness Test Suite" provide any test to measure Entropy of an 
   entropy source?
3. How to check "biased-ness" of a bit string?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. What research have you done? 2. What does the NIST documentation say? (you should read it) 3. What research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no such thing as the *"Entropy Rate" of a bit string*. That's shorthand for the [entropy rate of the process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate) that created the bitstring. Thus what's to be analysed to determine this entropy rate is how the bit string was produced, not the bitstring itself.

   If a bitstring `0000` was produced by four fair coin throws, the entropy rate of that process is 4 bit/bitstring, and the entropy rate of the process that created each bit of the bitstring is 1 (bit/bit). Knowing the bitstring is of no use in this determination.

   If a bitstring `0101` was produced by starting with `0` then alternating, then the entropy rate is zero.
2. The "NIST Randomness Test Suite" accepts a bitstring as input and determines if the hypothesis that the bits in this bitstring have been created independently and uniformly at random is acceptable, or should be rejected as too improbable.

   - When the hypothesis is true, the tests most often accept the hypothesis, but occasionally reject it (modern versions output a [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value), that is the probability that the hypothesis is rejected even though it actually holds).
   - When the hypothesis is false, what the test concludes depends enormously on the actual process.

     - If the process is a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) initialized with a constant bitstring, its entropy rate is zero, but the tests conclude just like if the hypothesis was true (and the entropy rate was 1 bit/bit).
     - If the process is a natural source that behaves distinguishably from the hypothesis (for example, if each bit is determined by 20 fair coin throws and is `1` if there was at least 10 heads; which is a source of independent bits sizably biased towards `1`), some tests in the suite are more likely to reject than they would be should the hypothesis hold; how likely depends on the source, and on which test.
3. To *check the "biased-ness" of a bit string*, first define *"biased-ness" of a bit string*; I know no acknowledged definition.

   To test if a bitstring could be from a source of random independent bits with no bias, count how many bits it has, and how many are `1`; then, armed with these two integers, use a (perhaps, one sided) [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test). This will tell if the hypothesis can be rejected with confidence. The monobit test in the NIST Randomness Test Suite does that, restricted to long bitstrings.

Comment: The 10 out of 20 example is slightly biased. I think you should make it clear in your answer whether that bias is intentional.

Comment: @fgrieu thank you :) that was helpful. It also cleared some of my confusions

Comment: @fgrieu By biased-ness I meant that whether we can predict the upcoming next bit of a binary sequence or not i.e, the bit string is biased towards 0s or 1s or towads none (incase of unbiased). In other words, the probability of upcoming bit to be 1 or 0 should be (ideally) 0.5